# Easy way to access protocol buffer field

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers

Have such .proto file structure

```
{
    session{
    field1 = value;
    field2 = value;
    ...
    }
object1{
    Object1field1 = value;
    Object1field2 = value;
    ...
}
object1{
    Object1field1 = value;
    Object1field2 = value;
    ...
}
object2{
    Object2field1 = value;
    Object2field2 = value;
    ...
    SubObject1{
    SubObject1field1 = value;
    SubObject2field2 = value;
    ...
    }
}    object2{
    Object2field1 = value;
    Object2field2 = value;
    ...
    SubObject1{
    SubObject1field1 = value;
    SubObject2field2 = value;
    ...
    }
}
```

}
Simply saying have complex hierarchical structure. Object1 or Object2 for example could be repeatable. Is it possible to write universal methods which will return fields values as base objects like int, bool, string, datetime or simply string? I'd like to get following access by string literal:

```
public object GetFieldValue(int number, string fullPath)
```

Where fullPath could be specified like this for example:

```
fullPath = "object1.Object1field1";
```

number necessary for repeated fields: number could be equal to 0 for first "object1" and 1 for second, for example. Also necessary method to get object1 repeats count by field name:

```
public int GetFieldCount(string fieldName)
```

And also need similar way to access SubObjects to any nested level. Is that possible? Is there is an alternative to protocol buffers hardcoded classes?

Comment: What protocol buffers library are you currently using?

Comment: Seems protobuf-csharp-port, they give me pregenerated class and Google.ProtocolBuffers.dll for my project. Which one is better for such task? There are very few documentation and examples for both C# Protocol Buffers libraries.

Comment: can I also ask: it seems to me that the primary way to do this would be to deserialize the data then use reflection (or something like FastMember) to get the values by name. Is this an option? If you don't know the object definition, you can't access by name, as protobuf does not store names.

Comment: Yes, data is deserialized. Of course I know object definition but I'd like to some generic method access to process fields by stored user defined settings (mappings) like mentioned "object1.Object1field1". Because I have hundreds of fields which I'd like to read automatically. In other case I'll need to hardcode each - not very good. Why pbuff does not provide such?! In that case it is not so convenient as XML though.

Comment: Why not to deserialize it to some easier structures which could be accessed automatically like: Dictionary<string, object>, for example, where string it is field name, and object could be: int, string, bool, datetime, and next Dictionary<string, object> for nested level?

Comment: What about FindFieldByPropertyName?

`public static object GetPropVal<T>(this T pbMsg, string propName) where T : IMessage
        {
            if (null == pbMsg)
                return null;

            FieldDescriptor fd = pbMsg.DescriptorForType.FindFieldByPropertyName(propName);
            return pbMsg[fd];
        }`

Comment: Does Your protobuf-net allows desired access? About FastMember: seems the only way to install it is using NuGet, however I use VS 2008.

Comment: simply: what you are describing is not a feature of serialization - no serializer I know of offers that. Yes FastMember could help you do that. As could raw reflection. If you want to try FastMember, I could probably put a dll dump on the site, if you want.

Comment: If only to deserialize pbuff to XML?

Comment: I don't understand that comment/question - however, it is very easy to have a model that can be used by both XmlSerializer and protobuf-net

Comment: May be some misunderstanding here: I work only with received deserialized data. If there an easy way to convert pbuff data to XML? In that case I'll be able to read values in desired behaviour. However think XML will be much slower.

Comment: do you mean **just** the data (I.e. just a stream), or do you know the object layout/schema too? If you **just** have the raw data, you cannot produce xml as you don't have any names. If you have the schema: just deserialize from protobuf, and serialize in XML. I do this type of switch *all the time*. However, I use protobuf-net which is more *idiomatic* of .net serializers, so works well with XmlSerializer

Comment: Yes, I have both. Could You give me some link with example how to do that, please? Also, does protobuf-csharp-port allows to serialize to XML, or only Your protobuf-net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm... definitely protobuf-csharp-port has everything necessary for this task, example:

```
IMessage object2 = (IMessage)original[original.DescriptorForType.FindFieldByName("object2"), 0];
IMessage subObject1 = (IMessage)object2[object2.DescriptorForType.FindFieldByName("SubObject1")];
int value = (int)subObject1[subObject1.DescriptorForType.FindFieldByName("SubObject1Field1")];
```

As all types derived from **IMessage**. Will return to it. ;)

Comment: BTW, just have read RELEASE NOTES for Version 2.4.1 - it allows to:
- Addition of the "Google.ProtoBuffers.Serialization" assembly to support reading and writing messages to/from XML, JSON, **IDictionary<,>** and others. which is just perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

Relating to the xml/protobuf conversation; my *understanding* is that protobuf-csharp-port uses immutable types, so doesn't work well with things like XmlSerializer. protobuf-net, by contrast, deliberately sets out to use standard mutable POCO types, either your existing DTOs, or generated from .proto via protprotogen; either way, we end up with a generated type something like:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Bar Something {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Bar {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

(give or take some complexity)

Then converting from a protobuf stream to xml is simply:

```
Foo foo;
using(var source = ...) {
    foo = Serializer.Deserialize<Foo>(source);
}
string xml;
using(var sw = new StringWriter()) {
    var ser = new Serializer(typeof(Foo));
    ser.Serialize(sw, foo);
    xml = sw.ToString();
}
```

now `xml` is the `XmlSerializer` representation of the same data in the `Foo` instance (and any sub-data such as `Bar`)

Comment: If protobuf-net generates such classes, in that case I like Your implementation much more, will try it instead of protobuf-csharp-port. And what protobuf-net will generate in You example if Bar is repeatable?

Comment: Cool, much more easier data structure for use and understanding than protobuf-csharp-port - which is terrible actually. With Your protobuf-net it is much easier to access fields by reflection and implement access I need.

Comment: @AlekseyK well, do you plan on using XmlSerializer? or DataContractSerializer? In particular, the attributes for XmlSerializer and DataContractSerializer **are** mutually exclusive (I don't add this restriction just for giggles...). Since you are talking about xml, I would **assume** XmlSerializer is your best option

Comment: Thanks, Marc, selected XmlSerializer also.

Comment: BTW, whether Your protobuf-net generated classes or library have some internal reflection: to access fields values by name? Or only way to access them by name is using C# reflection or FastMember? I ask because thought iteration over all the properties could be very slow, isn't it?

Comment: @AlekseyK oh protobuf-net has some truly crazy meta-programming - but nothing to do with names (the spec doesn't use names at all). If you are doing lots of reflection, something like FastMember will help you avoid paying too much "tax" for reflection, but in moderate doses reflection isn't a problem.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, what if You extend Your code generation to something like this:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo : IGetFieldsByName {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Bar Something {get;set;}
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Bar : IGetFieldsByName {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int Id {get;set;}
}
```

i.e. to inherit all classes from same interface IGetFieldsByName?Then it will be easy to implement behaviour I like: access fields by "object.name" literal. What do You think about?

Comment: I think that has nothing whatsoever to do with protocol buffers (protobuf never uses names... Ever).

Comment: I see, however protobuf-csharp-port has some. Could You put fast-member dlls for VS2008 (.Net 3.5) to Download section of Google Code please as You proposed earlier please?

Comment: I'm in meetings all today, but will do later

Comment: Thanks anyway, probably somebody will need it.